# Custom memory caching allocator in C

Tags: c, memory-management

Over the weekend I built a fairly simple allocator:

```
struct FreeOnes { //data structure holding the pointers to free blocks
    int len;
    void** array;
    int capacity;
};

void append(struct FreeOnes* f, void* what){ //add a free block to FreeOnes
    if (f->len < f->capacity){
        f->array[f->len++] = what;
    } else {
        f->capacity *= 2;
        f->array = realloc(f->array, sizeof(void*) * f->capacity);
        f->array[f->len++] = what;
    }
}

void* pop(struct FreeOnes* f){
    return f->array[--f->len];
}

struct FreeOnes* newFreeOnes(int capacity){ //create a new FreeOnes datastructure
    struct FreeOnes* f = malloc(sizeof(struct FreeOnes));

    f->len = 0;
    f->capacity = capacity;
    f->array = malloc(sizeof(void*) * capacity);

    return f;
}

struct Size { //the information neccessary to allocate a block
    int size; //the byte size
    int alignment; //the alignment to the memory-array
};

struct Size find(int size){ //find at wich alignment the size fits inside
    int i = 2;
    int iter = 0;
    while (i <= size) {
        i *= 2;
        iter ++;
    }

    struct Size s;
    s.size = i;
    s.alignment = iter - 1;

    return s;
}

struct FreeOnes** sizes; //holds a free ones data structure for all power of 2 sizes until 2^32

void* allocChunk(struct FreeOnes * f, size_t size, int alignment, int howMuch){ //chunk allocate memory,
//used by alloc and returns a pointer to the first element in the chunk

    void* pool = malloc(size * howMuch);
    void* at = pool;

    for (int i = 0; i < howMuch; i++){
        void* pointer = at;
        at += size;
        int* p = (int*) pointer;
        *p = alignment; //store the alignment meta-date
        append(f, pointer+ sizeof(int));
    }

    return pop(f);
}

void* alloc(struct Size s){ //allocate, memory for a size
    if (sizes[s.alignment]->len > 0){ //if already allocated memory, just this instead
        void* pointer = pop(sizes[s.alignment]);
        return pointer;
    } else if (s.alignment < 6){ //allocate chunk and use the first element
        return allocChunk(sizes[s.alignment], s.size, s.alignment, 100);
    } else if (s.alignment < 12){ //allocate chunk and use the first element
        return allocChunk(sizes[s.alignment], s.size, s.alignment, 20);
    } else if (s.alignment < 24){ //allocate chunk and use the first element
        return allocChunk(sizes[s.alignment], s.size, s.alignment, 5);
    } else { //so big not worth allocating chunk for, simply return pointer to malloc initialized memory
        void* pointer = malloc(s.size);
        int* p = (int*) pointer;
        *p = s.alignment; //store the alignment meta-date
        return pointer+ sizeof(int);
    }
}

void dealloc(void* pointer){ //free the pointer, and return it to the freeOnes vector
    int s = *((int*) (pointer - sizeof(int)));
    append(sizes[s], pointer);
}

void init(){ //initialize the program memory needed for alloc and dealloc
    sizes = (struct FreeOnes**) malloc(sizeof(struct FreeOnes*) * 32);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        sizes[i] = newFreeOnes(100);
    }
}
```

The allocator performs very well on this slightly biased benchmark:

> ```
> struct LinkedListAlloc { //small linked list benchmark
>   int x;
>   struct LinkedListAlloc * next;
> };
>
> long benchmark1(){ //benchmark using alloc
>   clock_t time1 = clock();
>
>   struct Size size = find(sizeof(struct LinkedListAlloc)); //the size for the linked list, in the format for alloc
>
>   for (int iter = 0; iter < 1000; iter++){
>
>       //create the linked list
>       struct LinkedListAlloc* root = alloc(size);
>       root->x = 0;
>       struct LinkedListAlloc* last = root;
>
>       for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
>           struct LinkedListAlloc* tmp = alloc(size);
>           tmp->x = i;
>           last->next = tmp;
>           last = tmp;
>       }
>
>       struct LinkedListAlloc* current = root;
>
>       while (1) {
>           if (current->x == 999){ dealloc(current); break; }
>           struct LinkedListAlloc* tmp = current;
>           current = current->next;
>           dealloc(tmp);
>       }
>
>   }
>
>   clock_t time2 = clock();
>
>   return time2 - time1;
> }
>
> long benchmark2(){ //benchmark using malloc
>   clock_t time1 = clock();
>
>   size_t size = sizeof(struct LinkedListAlloc); //the size for the linked list
>
>   for (int iter = 0; iter < 1000; iter++){
>
>       //create the linked list
>       struct LinkedListAlloc* root = malloc(size);
>       root->x = 0;
>       struct LinkedListAlloc* last = root;
>
>       for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
>           struct LinkedListAlloc* tmp = malloc(size);
>           tmp->x = i;
>           last->next = tmp;
>           last = tmp;
>       }
>
>       struct LinkedListAlloc* current = root;
>
>       while (1) {
>           if (current->x == 999){ free(current); break; }
>           struct LinkedListAlloc* tmp = current;
>           current = current->next;
>           free(tmp);
>       }
>
>   }
>
>   clock_t time2 = clock();
>
>   return time2 - time1;
> }
>
> int main(){
>   init();
>
>   long took1 = benchmark1();
>   long took2 = benchmark2();
>
>   printf("alloc:  %ld\n", took1);
>   printf("malloc: %ld\n", took2);
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

The test using `alloc` and `dealloc` is ten times faster than the test using `malloc` and `free`.

What could I improve on for this allocator, eg. how to make it thread-safe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Bug 1

Here is a program that crashes when using your allocator:

```
int main(void)
{
    init();

    struct Size s = find(sizeof(short));

    short *pShort1 = alloc(s);
    short *pShort2 = alloc(s);
    *pShort2 = 0xffff;
    dealloc(pShort1);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason for the crash is that the allocator rounds up each size requested to the next power of 2, but then it steals 4 bytes to store some metadata.  When the size requested is 2 bytes, as in the example above, the allocator rounds up the size to 4, and then steals all 4 bytes to store the metadata, leaving no memory for the actual allocation.  What ends up happening is that the pointer returned is pointing at the metadata for another allocation.  Writing `0xffff` to that pointer clobbers the metadata for the other allocation and results in a crash when that allocation is deallocated.

This bug can happen whenever the size requested is 1 to `sizeof(int)-1` bytes less than a power of 2.  So for example, if an `int` is 4 bytes, then using sizes 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15, etc. are all unsafe.

#### Bug 2

If you allocate something bigger than \$2^{24}\$ bytes, you will get a pointer back that is 4 bytes smaller than what you requested.  The problem is with this code:

> ```
> } else { //so big not worth allocating chunk for, simply return pointer to malloc initialized memory
>     void* pointer = malloc(s.size);
>     int* p = (int*) pointer;
>     *p = s.alignment; //store the alignment meta-date
>     return pointer+ sizeof(int);
> }
> ```

As you can see, you call `malloc(s.size)`, but then steal one `int` from the front.  You then return a pointer to something which has only `s.size - sizeof(int)` bytes allocated.

#### Bug 3

The regular `malloc()` always returns a pointer aligned to the maximum required alignment for the system.  So for example, on some system let's suppose it always returns an 8-byte aligned pointer because a `double` on that system must be 8-byte aligned.

With your allocator, you always return something that is off alignment by `sizeof(int)` bytes because you put the `int` sized metadata right before the actual pointer returned.  So if someone tried to use your allocator to allocate space for a `double`, and `sizeof(int)` is 4, then the pointer returned would be misaligned by 4 bytes and not be suitable for use as a `double` pointer.

Comment: how would it be possible to fix, the third bug.

Comment: fixed all bugs!

Comment: @Coder3000 You've already fixed the bugs, but in response to your question, you should probably steal a "maximum alignment" sized chunk off the front instead of an int.  According to the [GNU C library documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html), their malloc always aligns to a maximum of 8 on 32-bit systems and 16 on 64-bit systems.  So if you steal 16 bytes off the front, you should be able to maintain alignment.